# NUC ETH Validators Linux Nethermind and Lighthouse resize disk space problem

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

With friend we have use Intel NUC and SSD 512GB for system and 2TB SSD drive for Windows 11 Pro virtual machine... by this manual proces :
https://someresat.medium.com/guide-to-staking-on-ethereum-ubuntu-lighthouse-773f5d982e03
We use Nethermind and Lighthouse

All was good but now after 5 months the 2TB SSD with virtual machine show me in Linux that it is used 80% .... we also update and sync new data and get used after then only 45% of drive...

So we buy new 4TB drive and copy Virtial machine files from 2TB drive to 4TB new SSD drive...

After restart all works fine but in linux show me that only 1,76TB of 4TB drive is used....

Paragon disk manager show me used 1,76TB on 4TB drive and 1,76TB unused ....

Please tell me how to resize SSD 4TB that it all be used not just only 1,76TB ....

Please for help step by step...

best regards to all
alesk76

Comment: Show the output of `sudo fdisk -l` please.  It may be simple as one command or a handful of commands depending on how the filesystem was set up.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu on a virtual machine from Windows? Because then this seems like a Windows question.

Comment: Hi Arthur ... before when I have Windows VM on 2TB it takes me the whole drive but after I have copy files to 4TB it use the same space as before on 2T.. it doesnt use the whole 4TB new space....